# Permission Deploy Change Sets Error When Saving a Profile

Tags: permissions, profile

I have profile "Test". When I click Edit and then Save I get the following error message:

[image]

This is just a part of a huge error message, which lists all problem objects. The last part of this message is:

[image]

If we look at the Banks custom object permissions, the profile doesn't have a Create permission on it. That's what error says too.

[image]

What interesting is when I turn on the Modify All Data check box for this profile (all permissions for object automatically checked) and save the profile, it works - the save is done successfully.

[image]

But when I Edit the profile again and uncheck the Modify All Data and all Permissions for Bank except Read permission, it is saved successfully too. This is weird enough because previously the error said that Create permission on Bank is required, however it allowed to save the Profile without this permission. Why is it so?

Comment: You're looking the wrong Modify All Data; check the System Permissions instead.

Comment: Where can I find those? I don't see System Permissions in the Profile Edit window.

Comment: My apologies, in the Classic Profile editor, it's "Administrative Permissions".

Comment: The thing is I checked Modify All Data in the Administrative Permissions section and saved. After that I unchecked Modify All Data in the Administrative Permissions, unchecked Permissions for Bank (except Read permission) in the Custom Object Permissions and saved... which appeared to be success. What interesting is technically I returned to the state when I was getting that error. It seems that check Modify All Data - save - uncheck Modify All Data and Bank Permissions (i.e. return to previous state) just fixes the problem. But I'd like to know why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll find that Deploy Change Sets has also been disabled as a result of the edit. If not, there's a bug. Only administrators can deploy change sets, because they can change the permissions by using the change set. Whatever it is you're trying to do is likely to end up violating security or causing further errors down the road.

Comment: @sfdcfox, you're right Deploy Change Sets permission was the problem. I just unchecked it and could save the Profile from the first try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will mark this as the correct answer until @sfdcfox posts his answer.

Deploy Change Sets permission was the problem. I just unchecked it and could save the Profile from the first try.